# `Docker logs` erroneously appears empty until container stops

Tags: python, docker

When running a Docker container that calls a Python process, running **`docker logs #####` will return nothing**, despite events happening inside the container which emit to `stdout`. Noting appears in the logs until I run `docker stop ######`, in which case the expected output is returned. The same is true with `docker logs -f #####`— nothing appears, even when expected, until after the container is stopped.

This is very cumbersome for debugging. **Why might this happen?** Is there a setting I can change to ensure the logs are updated in real-time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be happening because stdout and stderr are buffered streams.

> When interactive, stdout and stderr streams are line-buffered. Otherwise, they are block-buffered like regular text files. You can override this value with the -u command-line option.

Try adding the -u flag.

```
CMD [ "python", "-u", "./your_script.py" ]
```

Or, as pointed out by David Maze, you could set the [PYTHONUNBUFFERED environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED) and achieve the same result.

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

You could also flush stdout everytime you call print().

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Alternatively, see the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html).

Comment: The [`PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED) has the same effect, and it's reasonably common to see `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` in Dockerfiles for this reason.