# How to prevent Docker from messing with subprocess output order? (MCVE included)

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, stdout, stderr

Consider this `issue.py` file:

```py
import subprocess

print('Calling subprocess...')
subprocess.run(['python', '--version'])
print('Subprocess is done!')
```

Executing `python issue.py` manually yields what I expect:

```
Calling subprocess...
Python 3.9.0
Subprocess is done!
```

However, if I execute this inside a Docker container, something weird happens:

```
$ docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/issue python:3.9.0 python /issue/issue.py
Python 3.9.0
Calling subprocess...
Subprocess is done!
```

**How can I fix this, to make Docker respect the correct output order?**

Notes:

- This problem also happens with `stderr`, although the above [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) does not show it.
- The MCVE uses the `python` image directly but in my real use case I have a custom image from a custom Dockerfile which uses `FROM python`.
- Using `capture_output=True` in the `subprocess.run` call and then printing the captured output is not an option for me because my real use case invokes a subprocess that prints information over time to `stdout` (unlike `python --version`) and I cannot wait for it to complete to print the entire output only after that.

Comment: Does the `python -u` flag or `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` environment variable help?  ([What is the use of PYTHONUNBUFFERED in docker file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812009/what-is-the-use-of-pythonunbuffered-in-docker-file); [`Docker logs` erroneously appears empty until container stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58701233/docker-logs-erroneously-appears-empty-until-container-stops).)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes!! That worked!! Awesome, thank you very much. Can you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidMaze pointed out in a comment, I just needed to set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable to `1`. This can be done for example with:

```
docker run --rm -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 -v $(pwd):/issue python:3.9.0 python /issue/issue.py
```